# Flutter MultiBlocProvider Performance

Tags: android, performance, flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have a `MultiBlocProvider` assigned for an app that has a **Bottom Navigation Bar** to navigate through main routes like *Home*, *Search*, *Wishlist* ...

I use `setState(){}` to change the `currentPage` for each route.

Recently I've added **Blocs** to each of them by using `flutter_bloc` package and I'm using `BlocProvider` to provide the bloc to each `BlocBuilder`,

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: PageStorage(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                  child: BlocProvider<WishlistBloc>(
                      create: (BuildContext context) => WishlistBloc(WishlistRepository()),
                      child: currentPage),
              ),
              bottomBar(currentPageScroll)
            ],
          ),
          bucket: bucket,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Is it ok to use `MultiBlocProvider` to provide all the BlocsProviders I need?**

they could be more than 10 providers, would it affect the performance of the app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely OK, MultiBlocProvider created for this purposes. But you need to understand, that if you with your creation also send(for e.x.) initialize event which started loading in all 10 blocs some data you will have some issues. So, if you will have some performance issues, please create separate SO question and community will help to find root-cause of this.